# Creating a nested map using groupBy but collecting into a different type of Object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So I have this code that "works" (replacing some names for simplicity):

```
 Map<String, Map<String, ImmutableList<SomeClassA>>> someMap =
      someListOfClassA.stream()
      .filter(...)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::someCriteriaA,
            Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::someCriteriaB, GuavaCollectors.toImmutableList()
            )
      ));
```

However, I want to change this code so that instead we are creating new SomeClassB after grouping the SomeClassA. So if the classes look like this:

So for example, (assuming they both have all args construct

```
class SomeClassA { 
    String someCriteriaA;
    String someCriteriaB;
    T someData;
    String someId;
}

class SomeClassB {
    T someData;
    String someId; 
}
```

I'd want to be able to instead create

```
Map<String, Map<String, ImmutableList<SomeClassB>>> someMap = 
    someListOfClassA.stream()
    .filter(...)
    . // not sure how to group by SomeClassA values while creating new SomeClassB instances
```

I'm not sure how this would fit into the code above. How can I construct instances of SomeClassB based on the values of SomeClassA?

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Collectors.mapping(SomeClassB::new, GuavaCollectors.toImmutableList())`

Comment: @4castle - could you provide some detail on how that would work? How do you get the values from the grouped SomeClassA objects into the newly created SomeClassB instances?

Comment: `SomeClassB::new` can be replaced with any lambda or method reference which converts a `SomeClassA` instance to `SomeClassB`. `Collectors.mapping` just runs the value through a function before collecting the output in the downstream collector.

Answer (score 0):

Use the collectors like that:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ImmutableList<SomeClassB>>> someMap = 
  someListOfClassA
    .stream()
    .filter(...)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::someCriteriaA,
               Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::someCriteriaB,
                 Collectors.mapping(someClassA -> new SomeClassB(), GuavaCollectors.toImmutableList()))));
```

Whereas you can replace `someClassA -> new SomeClassB()` with your code to transform the instance of `SomeClassA` to an instance of `SomeClassB`.

[Collectors.mapping()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) will simply apply the given function before the collection happens.